# Apollo gateway not picking up managed federation configurations

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

This could be quite new to everyone but hoping for the best to find out the solution.

I've been trying to setup apollo managed federation through ApolloGateway for federated my services by following the official documentation. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graph-manager/managed-federation/setup/#4-deploy-the-modified-gateway

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
APOLLO_KEY=service:service_name:hash
```

ApolloGateway

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import express from 'express';
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-express';
import {ApolloGateway} from '@apollo/gateway';
import {config} from 'dotenv';
config();

const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 7000;
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'localhost';
const nodeHost = process.env.NODE_HOST || 'http://localhost';
const apolloGatewayConfig: any = {
  __exposeQueryPlanExperimental: false,
};
if (nodeEnv === 'localhost' || true) {
  apolloGatewayConfig.serviceList = [
    {
      name: 'vendors',
      url: `${process.env.GMS_VENDORS_NODE_HOST}/graphql`,
    }
  ];
}
const gateway = new ApolloGateway(apolloGatewayConfig);

(async () => {
  const app = express();
  app.get('/health', (_, res: any): void => {
    res.send({gateway: true});
  });

  const {schema, executor} = await gateway.load(); // breaking point
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    executor,
    engine: true,
    subscriptions: false,
  });
  server.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/graphql'});

  app.listen({port}, () =>
    console.log(`API Gateway is ready at ${nodeHost}:${port}`)
  );
})();
```

at line `const {schema, executor} = await gateway.load();` it throws an error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: When`serviceList`is not set, an Apollo Engine configuration must be provided.`

I've been following official docs but not sure what am I missing here?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but I had a similar issue where my introspection queries would go through local gateway instead of Apollo Studio;

First, I had to deploy the individual services in a federation configuration through the CLI (as reporting schema directly is not available yet)

```
npx apollo service:push --graph=<graph> --key=<my-key> --localSchemaFile=src/schema.graphql --serviceName=<serviceName> --serviceURL=<serviceUrl> --variant=dev
```

Then, inside the gateway code I had to remove the `serviceList` from the `ApolloGateway` constructor as instructed from the [Apollo Studio setup docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/studio/managed-federation/setup/#2-modify-the-gateway-if-necessary):

> This option specifies the name and URL for each of your graph's implementing services. With managed federation, this information is no longer hardcoded in the gateway's constructor! Instead, the gateway regularly polls Apollo for this information. This enables you to add and remove implementing services from your graph without needing to restart your gateway.
>
> Remove the `serviceList` argument from your `ApolloGateway` constructor entirely:

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    { name: 'test', url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'},
  ]
});
...
const gateway = new ApolloGateway();
```

In your case, this should solve your issue but you should also update your use of Apollo Server as well. Instead of using `{ schema, executor }`, you can embed the `gateway` directly:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  subscriptions: false,
});
```